# Electron event emitter error while app.quit with closing all open renderer processes

Tags: node.js, electron

I have one main window listing all available servers with a status button which has the id of the server. An info window is opened after pressing the related status button - passing the id to the copy of info window, making the status button disabled. If the info window is closed, the info window passes back the id to the main window so it makes the status button enabled again. To do that, I'm using `main.js` as a proxy, listening to the renderer processes and exchange information between main window and info window.

The thing that I'm trying to do is to list servers. If they are online, get some information from multiple servers at once on different renderer processes (instance of info window).

The problem is I want all info windows to be closed if the main window is closed.

```
// App ready
app.on('ready', ()=>{
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({x : 0, y : 0 , width : 500, height: 600});

    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname : path.join(__dirname, 'windows', 'mainWindow.html'),
        protocol : 'file',
        slashes : true
    }));

    // Close the app if main window closed
    mainWindow.on('close', (e) => {
        let openedOnes = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows();
        openedOnes.forEach(wind => {
            if(wind.hasOwnProperty('custom')){
                wind.close();
            };
        });

        app.quit();
    });
});
```

While creating info window, I add a custom field to the `BrowserWindow` object:

```
BrowserWindow {
  _events:
   { blur: [Function],
     focus: [Function],
     show: [Function: visibilityChanged],
     hide: [Function: visibilityChanged],
     minimize: [Function: visibilityChanged],
     maximize: [Function: visibilityChanged],
     restore: [Function: visibilityChanged],
     close: [Function: callIntoRenderer] },
  _eventsCount: 8,
  devToolsWebContents: [Getter],
  custom: { server_id: '3' } }
```

So with the help of the custom field, I can get all opened server info instances.

But when I click close, the following part is failing at `main.js`;

```
ipcMain.on('window_closed', (e, item)=>{
    mainWindow.webContents.send('button_enable', item);
});
```

It raises the following error.

[image]

`main.js:53` is the line `ipcMain.on('window_closed'...`. By the way, if I omit this line everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what's happening is your `mainWindow` `close` handler gets triggered which tells other windows to close, which then fires off the `window_closed` event (I guess that's a custom event that you added?), and by the time`mainWindow.webContents.send` is called, the `mainWindow`'s close handler finished and the window closed.

Simply add an `isDestroyed` check before sending the message like so:

```
ipcMain.on('window_closed', (e, item)=>{
    if (mainWindow && !mainWindow.isDestroyed())
        mainWindow.webContents.send('button_enable', item);
});
```

---

Your other options (though arguably less optimal) are:

1. Set a flag when the main window is closing and have the `window_closed` handler return out if it sees the flag (surely there's no reason to send a `button_enable` message if we're about to shut everything down):

```
let mainWindowIsClosing = false;
mainWindow.on('close', (e)=>{
    mainWindowIsClosing = true;
    ...
    wind.close();
    ...
});

ipcMain.on('window_closed', (e, item)=>{
    if (mainWindowIsClosing) return;
    mainWindow.webContents.send('button_enable', item);
});
```

2. You can call the `destroy` method instead of `close` to avoid firing the `close` event for child windows. (though `window_closed` isn't an Electron event I believe, so it depends on how you've hooked everything up):

```
mainWindow.on('close', (e)=>{
    ...
    wind.destroy();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution. I think isDestroyed chek is the best way to solve that issue. I have tried your solution and it seems everything is ok, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution as follows;

```
mainWindow.on('close', (e)=>{
    mainWindow = null;
    try{
        let openedOnes = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows();
        openedOnes.forEach(wind=>{
            if(wind.hasOwnProperty('custom')){
                wind.close();
            };
        });

        app.quit();

    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Before closing the main window, i set the mainwindow to null. When an info window is closed, check if its not set to null, send the mainwindow an info window is closed and its status button should be enabled;

```
ipcMain.on('window_closed', (e, item)=>{
    try {
        if(mainWindow !== null){
            mainWindow.webContents.send('button_enable', item);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: I wonder, if you add a `closed` handler on the `mainWindow`, does it get triggered after you `null` it out? Typically, you should null out the window in the `closed` handler, not `close`. Your approach might prevent other window events from firing, which isn't ideal. Setting a flag like in my answer is likely more appropriate

Comment: You are right. I have checked the documents again and with closed event we should set the browserwindow object to null not with the close event.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Child/Parent BrowserWindows like here: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#parent-and-child-windows

You will get more easier all child windows with:

```
win.getChildWindows()
```

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#wingetchildwindows

Comment: Your problem with ipcMain.on('window_closed') is because you catch also your mainWindow close hook